Split the emacs screen into 2 windows side-by-side, with a different buffer in each window?
I'm trying to split the Emacs screen into two windows side-by-side (for example, the way that split-window-right does it), but I want a different buffer shown in each side.
For example ...
(get-buffer-create "buff-0")
(get-buffer-create "buff-1")
;;; and now split the screen side-by-side into two windows
;;; with the leftmost window containing "buff-0"
;;; and the rightmost window containing "buff-1"

If I use split-window-right, both windows end up containing the same buffer.
This is probably a very elementary elisp construct, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Oh, I figured it out. I had forgotten that the other-window function must be called with an argument.
I was previously confused because I was incorrectly using (other-window) instead of (other-window 1), and the switching between windows wasn't working.
Here's what I did that works ...
(get-buffer-create "buff-0")
(get-buffer-create "buff-1")
(split-window-right)
(other-window 1)
(switch-to-buffer "buff-1")
;;; fill the buffer the way I want
(other-window 1)
(switch-to-buffer "buff-0")
;;; fill the buffer the way I want

